# DateTimeControl dateboxes overlap GUI

Tags: wpf, xaml

What needs to be added in my xaml file to my DateTimeControl bit to prevent the date boxes from overlapping the top tabs and the vertical scroll bar in my GUI? It's quite annoying.  Here's a [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDAJH.png)

Here's how I have them in my xaml file...

```
<sapctrls:DateTimeControl 
    Margin="2,5,5,0" 
    Name="JOB_DATE_SOLDControl"  
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.Row="4" 
    ShowCheckBox="True" 
    Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProjectDataSource}, Path=Value.Properties[JOB_DATE_SOLD].Value,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
    />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: we need more information about your `sapctrls:DateTimeControl`

Comment: Please show enough XAML to reproduce the issue. What you've shown can't possibly be used to say anything with any confidence about what's wrong with your UI layout.